# Performance on highlighting words/lines in Vim

Tags: performance, vim, highlighting

I have a set of small functions in VimL highlight a line (or a word) depending on certain conditions.

You should consider the workings of the functions to act similar as the spelling (`:set spell`), underlining when the conditions are met.

I have found, however, that when the number of highlighted lines exceed about 75, there is a significant lag when moving. Either from side to side or up or down.

I had some convenient `AutoCommands` that I was enabling by default, (for example, to echo why the line is highlighted) but even with all of them disabled, as soon as I call the function that highlights everything, I can tell there is a huge lag.

This is what I am using to highlight a word:

```
call matchadd('MyCheck', '^\%'. line . 'l\_.\{-}\zs\k\+\k\@!\%>' . column . 'c')
```

And this is what I use to highlight the whole line

```
call matchadd('MyCheck', '\%' . line . 'l\n\@!')
```

The 75 number I use as a reference for determining a lag is just a reference, it is a bit of a sweet spot for me, but just to demonstrate that most anything beyond gets increasingly worse.

I also use the `SpellBad` highlighting for `MyCheck`, but seriously doubt that this causes any problems.

Is there something I could do differently to avoid the lag? Is `matchadd` the best option?

EDIT:
Just to make sure it is not any of my functions or code doing something weird, I opened a 500 line file and did this:

```
highlight link MyCheck SpellBad                                                      
for line in range(line('$'))
    call matchadd('MyCheck', '\%' . line . 'l\n\@!')
endfor
```

Which basically highlights every single line on the file. Everything clearly got impossibly slow.

Comment: You can move EDIT 1 to an answer and select it as the solution if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsetting cursorline has a drastic (positive) effect in performance.

I did `:set nocursorline` and now my movements (regardless of highlighting) are snappy as before.